# Visual Basic Login Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am making a login and register form for my website, and I need to know how I would be able to make it so that if people left the register form empty, or null, how I can stop my program from creating that account and that it would display an error message. Please let me know what you think. Thank you!

This is my registration form code:

Public Class Form2

```
Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs)
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Salesperson's name", "No entry")


    Else
    My.Settings.Username = TextBox1.Text
    My.Settings.Password = TextBox2.Text
    My.Settings.Save()
    MsgBox("Create Account", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Register")
    Form1.Show()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Hide()
    Form1.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    My.Settings.Username = TextBox1.Text
    My.Settings.Password = TextBox2.Text
    My.Settings.Save()
    MsgBox("Create Account", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Register")
    Form1.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

This is my login code:

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.Username And
    TextBox2.Text = My.Settings.Password Then
        Form3.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    Else
        MsgBox("Incorrect Username or Password!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
    Form2.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

ANY IDEAS??

Comment: Your title says visual basic, and the code looks like visual basic, but you tagged it as `c#`, wondering if you mis-tagged it.

Comment: Wait... the passwords are stored in a plain-text xml settings file?! That's really not good. You need to read about bcrypt.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `ShowDialog` method for the `Login` form as well as its `DialogResult`

The ideas are these:

1. To open your `Login` form by using `ShowDialog` which returns `DialogResult`, rather than by using `Show` (as what you do now).
2. On the closing of your `Login` form, you check all the inputs (say, by `TryParse` or such like). If any of the input is incorrect, you should assign `this.DialogResult` for your `Login` form as anything but `DialogResult.OK`
3. When the user input everything correctly and close the `Login` form correctly too (say, by pressing 'OK' `Button` or such like) then you set your `Login` form's dialog result as `DialogResult.OK`
4. In your main form, anything but `DialogResult.OK` as a result of `loginForm.ShowDialog()` should be considered an error, do something for the error.